# Use JQuery to display different state of button and show/hide contents

Tags: jquery, html, css

My website: [Live Working Example](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/validate/test.htm)

I have achieved so far the fading out and fading in of contents.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.clinical').click(function (event){
        $("#cl").fadeIn();
        $("#nc").fadeOut();
        $("#bth").fadeOut();
    });
    $('.nonclinical').click(function (event){
        $("#cl").fadeOut();
        $("#nc").fadeIn();
        $("#bth").fadeOut();
    });
    $('.both').click(function (event){
        $("#cl").fadeOut();
        $("#nc").fadeOut();
        $("#bth").fadeIn();
    });

});
```

I need help with the following if someone can assist:

1. By default since the clinical text is displayed, I want the clinical button to be in pressed state so it is differentiated from the other buttons.

CSS Code for #1:

```
#demo {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block; /* Change anchor to block element */
    width: 275px; height: 47px; /* Specify width and height of the image. Height is value of each individual button graphic */
    background-image: url(testBtn.png); /* Add the image as a background */
    background-position: top; /* Set the position to the top */
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 47px;       /* the same as your div height */
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #5E5E5E;
}
    #demo:hover {
        background-position: center; /* Set the position to the center */
    }
    #demo:active {
        background-position: bottom; /* Set the position to the bottom */
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    #nc {
        display: none;
    }
    #bth {
        display: none;
    }
```

1. Which ever button the user clicks the content should fade in (which is working) and the button to be in pressed state.
2. In IE the fading in/out is very choppy, can it be fixed?
3. The code be optimized to have less codes?

Comment: Please put your code in a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Please click on the link at the beginning, which includes the images and all the codes used :)

Comment: @SiKni8: We can't "fiddle" around as easy by just showing your site - it's easier to use a fiddle instead of a browser's inspector (at least for the task at hand). Also, not like you have a ton of code, but it isolates the problem.

Comment: Ok i thought the website would be easier, but sure let me fiddle it :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f54RW/

Comment: working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jue6t/1/ the one above does not include jquery lib

Comment: Sorry I didnt realize it. Thanks for correcting it. Updated the image location as well to give the full picture.

Comment: You have your `id`s and `classes` backward. `id`s must be unique and can only be used once, `classes` may be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the button you can add a class or use toggleClass, use css to add the styles you need for the "on" state. when you click a different button, you need to remove the class from the buttons and add it to the current button

Something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/jue6t/2/

```
    $('.button').on('click', function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('on')) {
            $('.button').removeClass('on');
            $(this).addClass('on');
        }
    });
```

The code can be tidy up a lot more but you get the idea

you can even use

```
$('.button.on').removeClass('on');
```

if you have an overall ID it would be wise to add that so it becomes

```
$('#myID .button.on').removeClass('on');
```

Comment: Works great, and easily used with color, but i have an image sprite.

Comment: so change the css to use the image sprite for the class "on", this is the only jquery you will need, the look of the button is all css

Comment: Why use `$(this)` and `$(".button')` interchangeably?

Comment: @BramVanroy button has more than just $(this), he has 3 buttons. The jquery on the fiddle an be simplified and optimized but I leave that to the OP

Comment: Huangism, i will work on putting all the patches together and make a working example... THANKS :)